# Symfony3 configuration component validation

Tags: symfony, symfony-config-component

Community I need your help. I have config file:

```
payments:
    methods:
        paypal:
           enabled: false
           allowed_countries:
              - <country>
              - ...
        credit_card:
           disallowed_countries:
              - <country>
              - ...
```

How can I validate using the TreeBuilder if arrayNode is containing only one of 2 allowed arrays: ***allowed_countries*** or ***disallowed_countries*** and throw exception if there is two arrays together? Symfony version 3.2

Comment: Please show your ConifgTreeBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more complex validation to your configuration tree builder by using [validation rules](https://symfony.com/doc/3.2/components/config/definition.html#validation-rules) with the [ExprBuilder](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Config/Definition/Builder/ExprBuilder.html).

This would look something like:

```php
$rootNode
    ->isRequired()
    ->validate()
        ->ifTrue(function($options) {
            return !($options['allowed_countries'] xor $options['disallowed_countries']);
        })
        ->thenInvalid('Either define allowed_countries or disallowed_countries, not both')
        ->end()
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('allowed_countries')
            ->scalarPrototype()->end()
        ->end()
        ->arrayNode('disallowed_countries')
            ->scalarPrototype()->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```